# Regex To match lines and save as first line

Tags: regex, perl

Hi I've been trying to write a REGEX to match text between a beginning "step start" and "step end" then use the first line after step start to save the file as, but I can't seem to get the REGEX to work. I'm using Perl to do it, but I can also use a JavaScript function.

REGEX

```
^step start\R(\w.+\w)\R(\w.+\w)+step end
```

SAMPLE DATA

```
step start
Block 1+
DMC-GAASIB0-00-48-21-02-01AAA-520A-A.xml
DMC-GAASIB0-00-48-21-02-01AAA-720A-A.xml
step end
step start
4026 through 4167 and 4170 through 4207
DMC-GAASIB0-00-79-11-01-00AAA-941A-A.xml
step end
4108 through 4124 and Block 1+
DMC-GAASIB0-00-91-28-00-19AAA-051A-A.xml
step end
step start
4242 through 4606
DMC-GAASIB0-03-48-21-02-01AAA-520A-A.xml
DMC-GAASIB0-03-48-21-02-01AAA-720A-A.xml
step end
step start
Aircraft 4010 through 4124
DMC-GAASIB0-00-08-41-01-00AAA-169F-A.xml
DMC-GAASIB0-00-08-41-03-00AAA-023A-A.xml
DMC-GAASIB0-00-91-93-7A-12AAA-051A-A.xml
step end
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What is `\R(\w.+\w)\R(\w.+\w)+` supposed to do?

Comment: Are you performing two separate matches: one for file name and one for file content?

Comment: Are you missing a `step start` before `4108 through 4124` or is that what the data looks like?

Comment: I can't get the REGEX to work for the string "Block 1+". Ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `\R` inside your repeating group and make it **lazy** to avoid matching overlapping start/end blocks:

```
^step start\R(\w.+)\R(?:\w.+\R)*?step end$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mpqdg3/4)

Non-capturing group `(?:\w.+\R)*?` allows line-break at the end to allow matching multiple lines before matching `step end`

Also it is safe to use `$` after `step end`.

Comment: Doesn't handle an empty or one-line block correctly.

Comment: I don't mean same line, I mean `"step start\nfoo bar\nstep end\n"`.

Comment: @anubhava it's not working on lines containing 1 Begin 1+.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand by `1 Begin 1+`. Can you edit question and provide a sample data for which this regex doesn't work.

Comment: @anubhava I've edited the test data to reflect Block 1+

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest matching the whole middle block of text first, then extracting the first line. Otherwise your `\w.+\w` pattern might unintentionally match `step end` and skip into the next block. For example,

```
step start
step end
step start
foo
bar.xml
step end
```

would otherwise be parsed as one single block with a filename (first line) of `step end`.

```
if ($string =~ /^step start\n(.*?)^step end$/ms) {
    my $block = $1;
    my $first_line;
    if ($block =~ s/\A(.*)\n//) {
        $first_line = $1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Here the `.*?` pattern (combined with the `s` flag) matches "any text at all, but as little as possible".

Alternatively you could split the input on `"\nstep end\n"` and strip the header from each block:

```
for my $block (split /^step end\n/m, $string) {
    $block =~ s/\Astep start\n(.*)\n//
        or next;  # malformed block
    my $first_line = $1;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that a straight regular expression solution is not robust enough for what you're doing. For one thing, it seems to require that you are slurping the whole file into memory before trying to match, which is not scalable to large inputs. Here is a one-pass solution that doesn't make filenames with spaces (replaces with `_`):

```
perl -ne '
  if($n==1){
    ($f=$_)=~s/\s/_/g;
    chop $f;
    open F,">$f";
  }
  if(/^step start/){
    $n=1;
  }
  elsif(!/^step end/){
    print F $_;
    ++$n;
  }'
```